# how to use the background command?

Tags: command

I want to launch a sleep in the background,

```
bg sleep 100
```

but sleep 100 seems not to exist, is there a mistake?
Do I have to launch a sleep before? It seems odd, as far as I would have no more control...

Comment: Have you checked out the manual for `bg`? It expects job id as the argument, not a shell command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, a command is run in the background with `&`.

So `sleep 100 &` should give you the results you are looking for.

You can also do as you posted in your answer, the problem is that when running `bg` you'd better tell what you want to run in the background so, after CTRL+Z you should run `jobs` and identify your job in case there are more than one, and after that run `bg %your_job_id`.